# subtracting the 'INT' column from the 'LMP' column, but only from the indexed row per unique 'ID'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to create a new column named 'sub' in the DataFrame and calculate its values by subtracting the 'INT' column from the 'LMP' column, but only subtracting from the latest row per unique 'ID' where the 'FM' column is set to'time0', I calculated FM as the follows but I dont know how to implement the sub column.

```
data = {
    'ID': [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'VIS': [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
    'STA': [float('NaN'), 4.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    'LMP': [float('NaN'), -35.0, 411.0, 773.0, 1143.0, 1506.0, float('NaN'), float('NaN'), float('NaN'), float('NaN'), float('NaN'), float('NaN')],
    'INT': [0.0, 0.0, 413.0, 777.0, 1171.0, 1509.0, 1967.0, 2310.0, 2627.0, 2970.0, 3357.0, 3768.0],
    'FM': [-1, -1, "time0", -1, -1, "time0", -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,-1]

}

sorted_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

sorted_data['FM'] = np.nan
for id in sorted_data['ID'].unique():
    filter_condition = (sorted_data['ID'] == id) & (~sorted_data['LMP'].isnull())
    if filter_condition.any():
        last_row_index = sorted_data.loc[filter_condition].index[-1]
        sorted_data.loc[last_row_index, 'FM'] = 'time0'

sorted_data['FM'] = sorted_data['FM'].fillna(-1)
```

Expected output should be calculated as this :

```
'sub': [float('NaN'), 0-411.0,413-411, 777-1509.0 , 1171.0-1509.0 ,1509-1509, 1967.0-1509, 2310.0-1509,2627.0- 1509, 2970.0-1509, 3357.0-1509,3768.0-1509]
```

Comment: your output doesn't have the same shape as the input, can you clarify?

Comment: Can you check the values for ID 2? I get a result that is slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code that subtracts the INT column from the LMP column at time0

```py
data = {
    "ID": [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "VIS": [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
    "STA": [float("NaN"), 4.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    "LMP": [
        float("NaN"),
        -35.0,
        411.0,
        773.0,
        1143.0,
        1506.0,
        float("NaN"),
        float("NaN"),
        float("NaN"),
        float("NaN"),
        float("NaN"),
        float("NaN"),
    ],
    "INT": [
        0.0,
        0.0,
        413.0,
        777.0,
        1171.0,
        1509.0,
        1967.0,
        2310.0,
        2627.0,
        2970.0,
        3357.0,
        3768.0,
    ],
    "FM": [-1, -1, "time0", -1, -1, "time0", -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
}

sorted_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

lmp_at_time0 = (
    sorted_data.groupby(["ID"])
    .apply(lambda grp: grp[grp["FM"] == "time0"]["LMP"])
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns=["level_1"])
)
lmp_at_time0.columns = ["ID", "LMP_at_time0"]
sorted_data = sorted_data.merge(lmp_at_time0, on="ID", how="left")
sorted_data["INT"] - sorted_data["LMP_at_time0"]
```

Comment: Note that in your example you use numbers 413, and 1059 from the INT column which was a bit confusing to me, I think you meant 411 and 1056 right  from the LMP column right?

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt produce the expected result, did you test it?

Comment: Yes yes you are right

Comment: The expected output are updated marwan

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# get the last time0 value per ID
mapper = (sorted_data
          .loc[sorted_data['FM'].eq('time0')]
          .drop_duplicates(subset='ID', keep='last')
          .set_index('ID')['LMP']
         )

# map and subtract
sorted_data['sub'] = sorted_data['INT'].sub(sorted_data['ID'].map(mapper))
```

Output:

```
    ID   VIS  STA     LMP     INT     FM     sub
0    0   0.0  NaN     NaN     0.0     -1     NaN
1    1   0.0  4.0   -35.0     0.0     -1  -411.0
2    1   1.0  7.0   411.0   413.0  time0     2.0
3    2   2.0  7.0   773.0   777.0     -1  -729.0
4    2   3.0  7.0  1143.0  1171.0     -1  -335.0
5    2   4.0  7.0  1506.0  1509.0  time0     3.0
6    2   5.0  2.0     NaN  1967.0     -1   461.0
7    2   6.0  2.0     NaN  2310.0     -1   804.0
8    2   7.0  2.0     NaN  2627.0     -1  1121.0
9    2   8.0  2.0     NaN  2970.0     -1  1464.0
10   2   9.0  2.0     NaN  3357.0     -1  1851.0
11   2  10.0  2.0     NaN  3768.0     -1  2262.0
```